# URL rewrite doesn't seem to be working

Tags: configuration

We have the following rewrite rules in our config:

```
<encodeNameReplacements>
    <replace mode="on" find="&amp;" replaceWith=",-a-," />
    <replace mode="on" find="?" replaceWith=",-q-," />
    <replace mode="on" find="/" replaceWith=",-s-," />
    <replace mode="on" find="*" replaceWith=",-w-," />
    <replace mode="on" find="." replaceWith=",-d-," />
    <replace mode="on" find=":" replaceWith=",-c-," />
    <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
  </encodeNameReplacements>
```

However when I create new items with spaces, the urls have '%20's in them.  There are no includes that are overwriting this.  We did switch over to MVC renderings from Layouts a while back, could this have effected the url's?

Comment: How are your URLs being written? Are all URLs affected or only some?

Comment: Ah, just checked, and no, it's only happening in one section of the site.  What could be causing it to work in one place but not the other?

Comment: My guess is the way that those URLs are being written out to the page. Can you post the code where you are turning the `Item` into a URL? My guess is it's in there somewhere.

Comment: You were right - it looks like we were rewriting the urls for this new section to account for making them shorter.  We were using the name of the item to write the url...  So, I've adde the necessary replacements and it's working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the code where the URLs are being generated to ensure that you're using the `LinkManager` to generate your URLs and not simply the items' names or display names. This will ensure that the `encodeNameReplacements` are taken into account when generating the URLs.

Comment: Currently it seems to be using Sitecore.Context.RawUrl.